# How to access local api on the deployed firebase application?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have created a simple todo app for learning purposes. It is a full stack website that consists of a static html file with js script that is accessing api on the same host. Backend is build on node.js with express framework and mongodb. Everything works fine on a local server, that I start with cmd:

> firebase serve --only functions,hosting

However when I deploy the app to the firebase cloud with cmd:

> firebase deploy

I cannot access JSON file that should be served under /api/todos. Instead I receive 503 error: [image]

The app/api/todos also does not work and gives error: Cannot GET /app/api/todos

I can access the file locally:[image]

How can I access my JSON file after the deployment? How the route /app/api/todos would be translated in the app that is deployed?

Answer (score 2):

You should rewrite your /api route from `hosting` to `functions` in `firebase.json` file

Take a look to this [link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config?hl=it)

Comment: Hey, I have everything redirected to express app as per the documentation:   "hosting": {
      "rewrites": [{
      "source": "**",
      "function": "app"
    }] I don't understand why this works when served on local PC and not in the firebase cloud. Is that is what you advised me to do?

Comment: In local it redirect automatically, but in deploy you have to rewrite certain routes of function